# Using FileInputFormat.addInputPaths to recursively add HDFS path

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I've got a HDFS structure something like

```
a/b/file1.gz
a/b/file2.gz
a/c/file3.gz
a/c/file4.gz
```

I'm using the classic pattern of

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(conf, args[0]);
```

to set my input path for a java map reduce job.

This works fine if I specify *args[0]* as *a/b* but it fails if I specify just *a* (my intention being to process all 4 files)

the error being

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://host:9000/user/hadoop/a
```

How do I recursively add everything under *a* ?

I must be missing something simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version of Hadoop. Here is the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193) for the same. It's still in open state. Either make the changes in the code and build the binaries or wait for it to be fixed in the coming releases. Processing of the files recursively can be turned on/off, check the patch attached to the JIRA for more details.

Answer (score 5):

As [Eitan Illuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068063/eitan-illuz%20Eitan%20Illuz) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27294471/1718518%20here), in Hadoop 2.4.0 a `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` configuration property was introduced that when set to `true` instructs the input format to include files recursively.

In Java code it looks like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", true);
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
// etc.
```

I've been using this new property and find that it works well.

**EDIT:** Better yet, use this new method on `FileInputFormat` that achieves the same result:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance();
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
```

Comment: conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", true); worked for me in Hadoop 2.2.0 also