# FileStatus use to recurse directory

Tags: recursion, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have following directory structure,

```
Dir1
 |___Dir2 
  |___Dir3
   |___Dir4
     |___File1.gz
     |___File2.gz
     |___File3.gz
```

The subdirectories are just nested and donot contain any files

I am trying to use the following for recursing through a directory on HDFS.If its a directory I append `/*` to the path and `addInputPath`

```
arg[0] = "path/to/Dir1"; // given at command line

FileStatus fs = new FileStatus(); 
Path q = new Path(args[0]); 
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,q);

Path p = new Path(q.toString()+"/*");
fs.setPath(p);  

while(fs.isDirectory())
{
    fs.setPath(new Path(p.toString()+"/*"));
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,fs.getPath());
}
```

But the code doesnt seem to go in the `while` loop and I get `not a File` Exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is the *if* statement you are referring to?
Anyway, you may have a look at these utility methods which add all files within a directory to a job's input:

```
Utils:

public static Path[] getRecursivePaths(FileSystem fs, String basePath) 
  throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    List<Path> result = new ArrayList<Path>();
    basePath = fs.getUri() + basePath;
    FileStatus[] listStatus = fs.globStatus(new Path(basePath+"/*"));
    for (FileStatus fstat : listStatus) {
      readSubDirectory(fstat, basePath, fs, result);
    }
    return (Path[]) result.toArray(new Path[result.size()]);  
}

private static void readSubDirectory(FileStatus fileStatus, String basePath,
  FileSystem fs, List<Path> paths) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  if (!fileStatus.isDir()) {
   paths.add(fileStatus.getPath());
  }
  else {
    String subPath = fileStatus.getPath().toString();
    FileStatus[] listStatus = fs.globStatus(new Path(subPath + "/*"));
    if (listStatus.length == 0) {
      paths.add(fileStatus.getPath());
    }
    for (FileStatus fst : listStatus) {
      readSubDirectory(fst, subPath, fs, paths);
    }
  }
}
```

Use it in your job runner class:

```
...
Path[] inputPaths = Utils.getRecursivePaths(fs, inputPath);
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPaths);
...
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes that *if* was leftover from a previous edit. This worked well, I used a `FileSytem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)`